# What exactly is petuntse? (mineral)

Tags: geochemistry

What exactly is petuntse, the "china stone" used as one of two ingredients in porcelain along with kaolin?

T[he Wikipedia article (and books I have read) describe petuntse as a mineral containing feldspar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Petuntse). Well, fine, but there are a lot of minerals that are certainly not petuntse that contain feldspar. Feldspar is one of the most common minerals, so saying it is a material with feldspar in it, is not specific.

What is the specific composition of traditional petuntses used to make porcelain?

Answer (score 1):

According to [the Pottery Histories web site](http://www.potteryhistories.com/page58.html):

> **Petuntse**
>   Petuntse is a historical Chinese term for rocks with a high content of
>   mica and feldspathic minerals that have been used as one of the
>   ingredients in the manufacture of Chinese porcelain. It is generally
>   similar in composition and use to China stone. Petuntse, with china
>   clay, forms the base ingredients for hard-paste porcelains similar to
>   those produced in China in historic times. See China stone.

and

> **China stone (Cornish stone, Cornwall stone)**
>   China stone is a
>   feldspar-rich mineral derived from partially decomposed granite. China
>   stone includes feldspar, mica, fluorospar, quartz and other
>   granite-derived minerals such as kaolinite, but lacks iron-bearing
>   minerals.  China Stone is used worldwide as a flux in the manufacture
>   of ceramic bodies and glazes. In the United Kingdom, the material is
>   mined in one small area of Cornwall.

I don't know if this meets the degree of specificity that you were looking for.